# ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS - STEAM error while starting program : 32-bits libraries "missing" although in the system

Tags: software-installation

I've used Ubuntu for many years.

My Acer Aspire 7741 runs Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and receives the Internet over Ultra ADSL 25MB by WiFi.

APU: core i3 M380 (2,53Ghrz x4)
RAM: 2x4G pc3-10600S
DE: Gnome 3.28.2
Kernel: 5.3.0-46-generic

lshw reveals:

```
   *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             produit: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 2
             information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 18
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             ressources: irq:27 mémoire:f0000000-f03fffff mémoire:d0000000-dfffffff portE/S:1800(taille=8) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

I have installed Steam from the software center years ago but since the last  updates, and an upgrade to 19.10 Eoan, my Steam doesn't want to start.

It gives this error message :

```
<< You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libtiff.so.4
libva.so.2
libvdpau.so.1
libva.so.2
libva-x11.so.2
libxcb-shm.so.0
libxcb-render.so.0
libvorbisenc.so.2 >>
```

But they do exist in the folder home/user/.steam
So I have tried to :
- re-install Steam : no change
- uninstall then install (always from the software center), redownloading 1h games and so on : no change
- add libraries manually : ineffective cos them are already installed in the home/user/.steam
- erased my "/root" partition to a new ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS : no change
- erased my "/root" partition to a new same but 32 bits : working but very much slower facing my chipset under 64 bits
- erased again to the 64 bits 18.04.4 LTS : no change
-> no change, no change, no change !!!

I've tried to install the whole 32 bits libs from another repository (adding new repository) : same error !

I've tried `apt-get install` and run steam from the Ubuntu command line terminal window and get same error but the steam starts although the error message occurred, and my game is still very slower...

Do you know if steampowered must write a new "correction update" ? Or anything else ? (If my English is correct...)

Comment: Hello everybody !
Thx ymuch K7AAY for the edit work you did on my question !
I have some news :
I've re-partitioned my HDD (keeping /home) but with no "swap" partition : only a primary /boot -1024 MB in case of-, a logical /root and my logical /home with my users and programs configs.
After that, I installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 with internet connection but :
 -> no thrid-parties drivers (as graphical and wifi),
 -> no updates nor upgrades AFTER installation (I blocked them in the parameters).
Then I installed steam and dl my games : WORKING !
But when I'll need updates, what will happen ?